# How to add a comment in Symfony in the controller?

Tags: php, symfony, render, symfony4

I would like to add a comment in my article with symfony. But i don't understand why i have this error.

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, string given
```

My code in my controller :

```
 /**
     * @Route("blog/comment/{id}", name="article_comment")
     */
    public function comment(Article $article,Request $request, ObjectManager $manager)
    {

        $comment = new Comment();
        $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
           $comment->setArticle($article->getId());
           $comment->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());

           $manager->persist($comment);
           $manager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('blog_show', ['id' => $article->getId()]);
        }

        return $this->render('blog/createComment.html.twig', [
            'formComment' => $form->createView(),
            'article' => $article
        ]);
    }
```

In twig i use this for call the url :

```
<a href="{{path ('article_comment', {'id' : article.id })}}">Add new comment</a>
```

So i need to keep the id of the article for tell to the Entity Comment to add it in 'setArticle'
The code for show one article :

```
   /**
     * @Route("/blog/{id}", name="blog_show")
     */
    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        return $this->render('blog/show.html.twig',[
            'article' => $article
        ]);
    }
```

The twig form :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme formComment 'bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}

{{ form('formComment')}}


{% endblock %}
```

and the relations : in entity Comment :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Article", inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $article;
```

I think the parameter `article` is empty, and i don't know why.. Thanks everyone

Comment: Hi, I think you need to show us the code that is creating the form in the twig.

Comment: `form(formComment)`, `formComment` is a variable.

Comment: It's done i add the twig form and the relation.

Comment: Omg i'm so dumb.. Thanks @u_mulder  ... !!!!